# Splitting Multiple values inside a Pandas Column into Separate Columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with column which contains two different column values and their name as follows:

[image: Sample Dataframe]

How Do I transform it into separate columns?

[image: Expected Dataframe]

So far, I tried Following:

1. use `df[col].apply(pd.Series)` - It didn't work since data in column is not in dictionary format.
2. Tried separating columns by a semi-colon (`";"`) sign but It is not a good idea since the given dataframe might have n number of column based on response.

EDIT:
Data in plain text format:

```
d = {'ClusterName': ['Date:20191010;Bucket:All','Date:20191010;Bucket:some','Date:20191010;Bucket:All']}
```

Comment: Can you post the data as text so it's easy to work with? Preferably so we can recreate the dataframe using `pd.from_clipboard()`.

Comment: Did you try [`df["ClusterName].str.split(";", expand=True)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) followed by something like `pivottable` or `melt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
df2 = (df["ClusterName"]
       .str.replace("Date:", "")
       .str.replace("Bucket:", "")
       .str.split(";", expand=True))
df2.columns = ["Date", "Bucket"]
```

---

EDIT:

Without hardcoding the variable names, here's a quick hack. You can clean it up (and make less silly variable names):

```
df_temp = df.ClusterName.str.split(";", expand=True)
cols = []
for col in df_temp:
    df_temptemp = df_temp[col].str.split(":", expand=True)
    df_temp[col] = df_temptemp[1]
    cols.append(df_temptemp.iloc[0, 0])
df_temp.columns = cols
```

Comment: This works too but as I said, I want to automate this due to dynamic server response. something where I don't need to hard code any column names but rely on split and define.

Comment: That's fine, split on `;` and then split again on `:` to extract the column names...

Answer (score 1):

So .. maybe like this ...

Setup the data frame

```
d = {'ClusterName': ['Date:20191010;Bucket:All','Date:20191010;Bucket:some','Date:20191010;Bucket:All']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Parse over the dataframe breaking apart by colon and semi-colon

```
ls = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    splits = row['ClusterName'].split(';')

    print(splits[0].split(':')[1],splits[1].split(':')[1])

    ls.append([splits[0].split(':')[1],splits[1].split(':')[1]])


df = pd.DataFrame(ls, columns =['Date', 'Bucket'])
```

Comment: It works as intended. On my point #2. Is there a way to automate this for n number of columns? response carries variable columns packed in a single column 'ClusterName'. I guess,count number of attributes packed in 'ClusterName' and then unpack them using your method. split(':')[0 ] will yield column names and [1] will yield values.